# Logout in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session, authentication

My app is on express, mongoDB. I add  authorization by session. Don't work logout. There is the link on a page (this is  pug):

```
a(href="/logout") logout
```

It's handler:

```
app.get('/logout',  function (req, res, next)  {
  if (req.session) {
    // delete session object
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      } else {
        return res.redirect('/');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

When clicked, it displays this and redirect does not occur. If you delete everything except redirect, then redirect will work. But I need to delete the authorization session.

Comment: What session middleware are you using?

Comment: Session handling is no longer supported in vanilla express. You have to use a package called *express-session* for that.

Comment: I used express-session.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using passportjs, you need to call the **req.logout()**  to terminate a login session. See documentation [here](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/logout/)

Comment: I used express-session, not passport.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```js
app.get('/logout',  function (req, res, next)  {
    // If the user is loggedin
    if (req.session.loggedin) {
          req.session.loggedin = false;
          res.redirect('/');
    }else{
        // Not logged in
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```